# Can I pass a VBA variable into a called Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, excel, vba

I have a Powershell script to incorporate into an Excel VBA macro. Please reference this question:
[Powershell Regex: Replace only multiple spaces with tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023136/powershell-regex-replace-only-multiple-spaces-with-tabs)

This is the code in question Convert_To_Tab_Delimited.ps1:

```
gc 'foo.txt'| % { $_ -replace '  +',"`t" } | set-content "<my path>\temp.txt"
```

I need to get 'foo.txt' to be a VBA variable that I pass to it.  Basically a path string that is obtained from a select file dialog in VBA. The Powershell file will be called by this statement:

```
Shell(“powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted <pathname>\Convert_To_Tab_Delimited.ps1″, 1)
```

Is there a way to pass a string variable as an argument to the called Powershell script?  Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define parameters at the top of your script:

```
param([string]$path)
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($path)
# etc.
```

In VBA, you need to pass the parameter:

```
Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File <pathname>\Convert_To_Tab_Delimited.ps1 -path """ & pathVariable & """", 1)
```

Comment: Wow, I have some reading to do! So you'd use an ampersand and not a '+' sign in the VBA code?

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton I'll admit I haven't done VBA in a long time and I had to double-check that. I guess either one works here. This answer suggests you would want to prefer `&`:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1727709/517852

Comment: Ah, great! Sounds like it's easier to avoid issues by using & to concatenate strings! Thank you!

Comment: Any ideas why I can't seem to pass the parameter, it's like the PS script runs but doesn't do anything.

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton Two ideas: 1) Bypass is not a valid value for ExecutionPolicy. I think you mean Unrestricted. 2) If you are passing a path that contains spaces you will need to quote it. I have made edits to my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll test it later.  One question I have is why the need for the multiple quotes?  The extra sets of double quotes don't make sense to me.  Could you explain?  Thank you!

Comment: This still doesn't work, I must have something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton So I called the variable "path", but is it going to be a full path or just a file name. If it is just a file name, then it's going into either powershell's current directory or its working directory (yes, those are different), which might not be where you expect. I believe calling Read/WriteAllText will go to `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`. I would suggest passing the full path. Beyond that you may want to ask another question.

Comment: Currently I'm using the following code to replace the tabs in my file: `code` param([string]$FileToOpen) gc $FileToOpen | % { $_ -replace ' +',"`t" } | set-content "<my path to desktop>\temp.txt"   $FileToOpen is a pathname to file.