# How Can I pass multiple VBA variables into a called Powershell script?

Tags: vba, powershell

[Can I pass a VBA variable into a called Powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034887/can-i-pass-a-vba-variable-into-a-called-powershell-script).

With the help of the above post, I am able to pass one variable to PowerShell. I need to pass two variables, there I failed with the below script. Can someone please help me with it.

```
strCommand = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted  -file `\""C:\Users\n3540551\Desktop\cluster\remote.ps1`\"" -name `\""" & nameVariable & "`\"" -pass2 `\""" & passVariable & "`\"""
```

PowerShell script as below:-

```
param([string]$name)
param([string]$pass2)
$MyUserName = "cctv";
$MyPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass2 -asplaintext -force;
$MyCredentials2 = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-argumentlist $MyUserName,$MyPassword

$scriptblock = {if ((Select-String -Path "C:\ProgramData\Root.1.log" -Pattern "Mismatching SRP verifier") -ne $null){echo "Mismatching SRP verifier found. Please check File"}else{ echo "All Goood!"}}

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name -credential $MyCredentials2 -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Comment: What does your powershell script look like? We’d have to guess to help.

Comment: @DougMaurer PowerShell script as above

Comment: what's all the `\ you have in the call?

Comment: You only need one param block. `Param([string]$name,[string]$pass2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell parser only recognizes 1 `param` statement per block, so you need to change:

```
param([string]$name)
param([string]$pass2)
```

to

```
param(
  [string]$name,
  [string]$pass2
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that was the perfect fix.